# SQL microsoft query to Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

*Hello*, all from all countries.
I need a SQL query converted to ***LARAVEL 4.2***  cause i dont have yet the experience to manage it, my own !

The SQL is in **SQL server microsoft 2008**

`SELECT TOP(10) logst_data, LogSt_date, LogSt_studid 
FROM Home_LogStudents
WHERE logst_action = 225 
AND LogSt_sectionID = 257 
AND LogSt_date IN 
                (SELECT MIN(LogSt_date) 
                 FROM Home_LogStudents 
                 WHERE logst_data <> '0' 
                 AND logst_action = 225 
                 AND LogSt_sectionID = 257 
                 AND (LogSt_studid IN 
                                    (select home_id 
                                     FROM Hw_StudentClasses 
                                     INNER JOIN Home_Students 
                                     ON home_studid = Stclass_studid 
                                     WHERE Stclass_classid = (129))) 
                GROUP BY LogSt_studid) 
ORDER BY LogSt_data DESC`

*all i could do is in the NEXT PICTURE* :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u1NY.jpg) but the **$id** and **$class_id** are not 
recognizible in the $query....ALSO THE CODE:

```
$users = DB::Table('Home_LogStudents')
            ->select('LogSt_data','LogSt_date','LogSt_studid')
            ->where('LogSt_action','=',225)
            ->where('LogSt_sectionID','=',$id)
            ->whereIn('LogSt_date',function($query){
                $query->select('LogSt_date')
                        ->from('Home_LogStudents')
                        ->where('LogSt_data','!=',0)
                        ->where('LogSt_action','=',225)
                        ->where('LogSt_sectionID','=',$id)
                        ->whereIn('LogSt_studid',function($query){
                            $query->select('home_id')
                                    ->from('Hw_StudentClasses')
                                    ->join('Home_Students','Home_Students.home_studid','=','Hw_StudentClasses.Stclass_studid')
                                    ->where('Stclass_classid','=',$class_id);
                            }
                        )
                ->groupBy('LogSt_studid');
                })
        ->orderBy('LogSt_data','DESC')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

*Thank you in advance and only for looking !*

Comment: I think you should post your code here instead of a picture

Comment: but basically you need to `use($class_id)` because the anonymous function does not recognise the outer scope variables.

Comment: u mean istead of $query to put $id in the first subquery and in the second subquery to put $class_id ?

Comment: function($query) use($id, $class_id) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer ,it was easy so all i did was to use **Raw Query** cause the query was too complex to translate it to laravel or maybe  i couldnt do it  so i did this.....

```
$users = DB::select('SELECT     TOP (10) Home_LogStudents.LogSt_data, Home_LogStudents.LogSt_date, Home_LogStudents.LogSt_studid, Home_Students.home_firstname, Home_Students.home_lastname
FROM         Home_LogStudents
INNER JOIN  Home_Students
ON Home_LogStudents.LogSt_studid = Home_Students.home_id
WHERE     (Home_LogStudents.LogSt_action = 225)
AND (Home_LogStudents.LogSt_sectionID = '.$id.')
AND (Home_LogStudents.LogSt_date IN
                          (SELECT     MIN(LogSt_date) AS Expr1
                            FROM          Home_LogStudents AS Home_LogStudents_1
                            WHERE      (LogSt_data <> \'0\')
                            AND (LogSt_action = 225)
                            AND (LogSt_sectionID = '.$id.') AND (LogSt_studid IN
                                                       (SELECT     Home_Students_1.home_id
                                                         FROM          Hw_StudentClasses INNER JOIN
                                                                                Home_Students AS Home_Students_1
                                                         ON Home_Students_1.home_studid = Hw_StudentClasses.Stclass_studid
                                                         WHERE      (Hw_StudentClasses.Stclass_classid = ' .$class_id.')))
                            GROUP BY LogSt_studid))
ORDER BY Home_LogStudents.LogSt_data DESC
');
```

Actually i used outside the string the **$id** and the **$class_id**  by using **'.   $id.'** and the   **'.$class_id.'**

I Hope this helps you , so for complex queries... just use **RAW QUERIES**

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, but you need to pass argument `$id, $class_id` into anonymous function.

```
$users = DB::Table('Home_LogStudents')
            ->select('LogSt_data','LogSt_date','LogSt_studid')
            ->where('LogSt_action','=', 225)
            ->where('LogSt_sectionID','=', $id)
            ->whereIn('LogSt_date', function($query) use($id, $class_id) {
                return $query->select('LogSt_date')
                    ->from('Home_LogStudents')
                    ->where('LogSt_data','!=', 0)
                    ->where('LogSt_action','=', 225)
                    ->where('LogSt_sectionID','=', $id)
                    ->whereIn('LogSt_studid', function($query) use($class_id){
                        return $query->select('home_id')
                            ->from('Hw_StudentClasses')
                            ->join('Home_Students','Home_Students.home_studid','=','Hw_StudentClasses.Stclass_studid')
                            ->where('Stclass_classid','=', $class_id);
                        }
                    )
                ->groupBy('LogSt_studid');
                })
        ->orderBy('LogSt_data','DESC')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Ok i did it but now it says _Undefined property: stdClass::$home_firstname_  i use **home_firstname** from **Home_Students** table in my _blade view_ that was the point to access info from 2 different tables for the results of a test for the specific **$id** = test of the specific **$class_id** = class :(

Comment: I'm not sure, but you need to var_dump a single row result. I guess the result is array, not an object. so can you try `$row['home_firstname']` instead of `$row->home_firstname`?

Comment: Is there a simiral command like **"Select MIN"** of SQL Server for Laravel ? All i know its **take()** and **first();**

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error ... :(

Comment: There `limit()`, but I don't know if it works for MS SQL.

Comment: I think you should var_dump the data row to see what you got here

Comment: Ok i will try that and get back to you although i dont know exaclty the way

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'LogSt_date'. (SQL: select min([LogSt_date]) as aggregate)

Comment: you need to select min(column) from a_table. missing table doesn't work

Comment: **Undefined property: stdClass::$home_firstname**  omg now in the blade **_@foreach($users as $user)->home_firstname_**  ->  on the blade **field home_firstname not found in class User** ? wtf really.....i think i messed up something....thx bro for ur patience

Comment: I think because of this `->select('LogSt_data','LogSt_date','LogSt_studid')` you don't select enough columns to show.

Comment: thx a lot man i learn a lot from you, in the end i found a solution but i could do it in laravel sql i used raw query !

Comment: i will but i dont have yet the reputation , but my aswer i will pick it as correct okay ?

Comment: lol, you don't lose any reputation will you vote up my answer =)) sorry but I don't get you...